# pymodbus server callback fo particular modbus function code

Tags: callback, pymodbus

I have a Modbus server implemented with pymodbus. This server has a thread that update the internal registers to simulate a variable environment from the field. I need to update a file when I receive a frame containing a write function code. I tried to implement the CustomDataBlock as suggested [here](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/custom_datablock.html), but that's not exactly what I need: in this example, the code is called every time a value is changed, hence also in my "internal" updating writer function.
I want some code to be called only when my server receive a frame with writing function codes.
Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself:

1. inherit ModbusRtuFramer
2. overload processIncomingPacket function